# Why can't I approve a workflow anymore?

Tags: workflow, error

I'm the approver in the workflow and was able to approve initial two entries. For the new approval requests the option is disabled for me.
The status shows pending to everyone.
During troubleshooting I found out the duration in workflow was set to 3 days. Is that the issue?
I changed the duration to 100 days and see the same results.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.StackExchange.com! I did some minor editing which I help makes your question more clear. Feel free to let us know if it changes the meaning or you have more detail to add.